# Problem calling cytoscape.use() with multiple arguments using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, cytoscape.js

We're developing a UI written in Typescript, using [Cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/) and the [cytoscape-context-menus](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-context-menus) extension. According to the [installation instructions](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-context-menus#usage-instructions) for the extension it's supposed to be registered with cytoscape like so

```
import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import $ from 'jquery';
import contextMenus from 'cytoscape-context-menus';

cytoscape.use(contextMenus, $);
```

Registering the extension like that will result in the following Typescript compile error, however.

> ERROR in ....
> TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

Looking at the type definition file for cytoscape, the following code can be found at the bottom of index.d.ts

```
type Ext = (cytoscape: (options?: CytoscapeOptions) => Core) => void;
function use(module: Ext): void;
```

and following code in the Cytoscape index.js

```
// e.g. cytoscape.use( require('cytoscape-foo'), bar )
cytoscape.use = function( ext ){
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ); // args to pass to ext
  args.unshift( cytoscape ); // cytoscape is first arg to ext
  ext.apply( null, args );
  return this;
};
```

The compile error goes away if I do either of the following

- Update the type definition file to include a rest parameter, `function use(module: Ext, ...args: any[]): void;`
- Add `// ts-ignore` above `cytoscape.use(contextMenus, $);`

Am I correct in believing that the type definition file for Cytoscape needs to be updated?